# changing color vs2008 breakpoint marker

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've been looking for a couple of hours now, but can't figure out what option in visual studio 2008 controls the highlighting used for breakpoints. I have a darker theme and the lines are hard to read when entering a debugger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit the breakpoint while debugging, that line of code becomes the current statement so in Tools>Options>Fonts and Colors look for 'Current Statement' line and change the item foreground and background color to your liking...

Answer (score 0):

With the help of this link:

[How to change the color  of Visual Studio 2005/2008 current line  highlight bar?](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Microsoft/Development/.NET/Visual_Studio_2008/Q_23167850.html)

I think user Thejaka has the answer:

> Do you mean the "Current Statement"
>   that is highlighted in yellow by
>   default during debug step through?
>
> Select "Tools -> Options" menu item.
>
> Select "Environment -> Fonts and
>   colors" from the tree view on left.
>
> Select "Current Statement" in "Display
>   items" list box, then change the "Item
>   background" color.
>
> Press OK.